# How to update ez pages meta name in the zen cart?

Tags: php, zen-cart, zen

I am create new Page from EZ Pages of the zen cart and there is some default mata name  like

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Contact Us page of ABC company.LTD">
<meta name="description" content="Contact Us page of ABC company.LTD">
```

so i want to update it.

Please suggest me how can i update it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to install a [plugin](http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=746) available on the Zen Cart site.

You can always do it the hard way - edit your includes/languages/YOUR_LANGUAGE/meta_tags.php and change the EZ-Page code:

```
  define('META_TAG_DESCRIPTION_EZPAGE_#','');
  define('META_TAG_KEYWORDS_EZPAGE_#','');
  define('META_TAG_TITLE_EZPAGE_#', '');
```

to something like:

```
  define('META_TAG_DESCRIPTION_EZPAGE_1','My EZ-Page description');
  define('META_TAG_KEYWORDS_EZPAGE_1','some keywords go here');
  define('META_TAG_TITLE_EZPAGE_1', 'This is the page title');
```

and do that for EACH EZ-Page individually. Of course, the plugin is a much simpler solution since it gives you user-friendly control from the admin. Don't forget to read the plugin's instructions and backup your site before installing it!